# finding nodes with using attributename and node names

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have an xml file with this structure:

```
<pics> </pics>

<Node id="83" />DESCRIPTION<Node id="94" />}<Node id="95" />EMPLOYMENT<Node id="105" /> <Node id="106" />AGREEMENT<Node id="115" /> <Node id="116" />{<Node id="117" />TEXT<Node id="121" />}<Node id="122" /> <Node id="123" />EMPLOYMENT<Node id="133" /> <Node id="134" />AGREEMENT<Node id="143" /> <Node id="144" />THIS<Node id="148" /> <Node id="149" />AGREEMENT<Node id="158" /> <Node id="159" />
<pics> </docs>
```

I need to pick nodes with ids between 105 and 149. I have loaded xml in xmldocument using asp.net/vb.net.  Please suggest how to do it.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: Please, correct your XML, because now it isn't well-formed. Also provide more information about what exactly you want to extract from input XML.

Comment: Your xml doesn't seem valid.  Every one of your "Node" nodes is empty!  Is this a complete xml sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `/Node[@id > 105 and @id < 149]`

`xmldoc.SelectNodes("//Node[@id > 105 and @id < 149]")`